# Localized dates inconsistency

Tags: java, android, date, localization, date-formatting

I am localizing my date strings, but having issues.
I expect UK locales to have dayOfTheMonth then Month while US ones to have Month then DayOfTheMonth.

It seems to be the case for getMediumDateFormat but not for getDateFormat.

If I use:

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat
```

then I get:

UK: 25 Nov 2015
US: Nov 25, 2015

Which is what I expect (day and month are in reverse order)
However, if I use:

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat
```

Then I get:

UK and US: 25/11/2015

In both cases the format is: dd/MM/yyyy

Did I miss something here?
Is there a better way to get a localized short date format?